# Howto center images in a size defined table?

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment

I have the problem that I have a table which includes two images next to each other and below in the next line there is the caption of the image. The problem is that the images are not shown next to each other, they are up and down. My code:

```
\begin{table}[!ht]\label{tab:subsecfeeling}
\begin{tabular}{|p{7cm}|p{7cm}|}
\hline
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{Screenshots/Routing/closed_area_ex1.png}
\label{fig:closed_area_ex1}
& 
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{Screenshots/Routing/closed_area_ex3.png}
%\label{fig:closed_area_ex3}
\end{center}
\\ 
\hline
The shown route in this figure is the shortest path from current position to the destination. In this route there exists no closed area. & The shown route in this figure is avoiding the closed door. Therefore the shortest path is to use the way through the next office. \\
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

The images shows that the images are not next to each other. I want that they are next to each other and not up and down. Besides the text in the next line has to be line braked.

I tried also centering in the second image, but then the result was almost the same as I get now. How can put both images in two columns next to each other?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Since the assigned column widths are `7cm` each, have you tried `6cm` for the widths of the images?

Comment: Changing `{|p{7cm}|p{7cm}|}` into `{|p{6cm}|p{6cm}|}` is not changing anything. Also to reduce the size of the image from 0.7 into 0.6 or less.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear: I was suggesting you change `width=0.7\linewidth` to `width=6cm`, for the widths of the *images*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick fix is to use `center` environment. It seems that `center` environment and `centering` command are used.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]\label{tab:subsecfeeling}
\begin{tabular}{|p{7cm}|p{7cm}|}
\hline
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{Screenshots/Routing/closed_area_ex1.png}
\end{center}
\label{fig:closed_area_ex1}
& 
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{Screenshots/Routing/closed_area_ex3.png}
\end{center}
%\label{fig:closed_area_ex3}
\\ 
\hline
The shown route in this figure is the shortest path from current position to the destination. In this route there exists no closed area. & The shown route in this figure is avoiding the closed door. Therefore the shortest path is to use the way through the next office. \\
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

If `centering` command is preferred, one needs to put a \par (or an empty line) before the closing brace. `\centering` doesn't leave vertical space before and after it.

[image]

Codes

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]\label{tab:subsecfeeling}
\begin{tabular}{|p{7cm}|p{7cm}|}
\hline
{\vspace{0.2cm}\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{Screenshots/Routing/closed_area_ex1.png}
\par}
\label{fig:closed_area_ex1}
& 
{\vspace{0.2cm}\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{Screenshots/Routing/closed_area_ex3.png}

}
\label{fig:closed_area_ex3}
\\ \hline
The shown route in this figure is the shortest path from current position to the destination. In this route there exists no closed area. & The shown route in this figure is avoiding the closed door. Therefore the shortest path is to use the way through the next office. \\
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```