# Centering images in lyx

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, lyx

I am having some trouble in centering images in lyx and have read a [number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8422/how-to-include-graphics-with-spaces-in-their-path)
[of](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155154/howto-center-images-in-a-size-defined-table) [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188298/centering-images) on the topic. However, when attempting to apply the solutions from the answers the images are still not centered. The code in lyx is:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Figure5_RPC_Problem_1}\caption{Wider than figure text. Wider than figure text.}
\end{figure}
```

I tried using the centering commands:

1. `\centering\includegraphics{...}` when the figure is smaller than the text width
2. `\centerline{\includegraphics{...}}` when the figure is wider than the text width

```
\begin{figure}
\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Figure5_RPC_Problem_1}\caption{Wider than figure text. Wider than figure text. Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.}
\end{figure}
```

and

```
\begin{figure}
\centerline{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Figure5_RPC_Problem_1}\caption{Wider than figure text. Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.}}
\end{figure}
```

but the output is still the same. Next I tried using the **center** environment but the image is still not centered

```
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}
    \centerline{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Figure5_RPC_Problem_1}\caption{Wider than figure text. Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.}}
    \end{figure}
\end{center}
```

The document now looks like:

[image: centering images is lyx]

A link to the image can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1N53PIwksP9vzOK5hPBH2wKlx24kHSrtFgoiD3pFMW08/edit?usp=sharing).

**Edit:**

I have modified the code to:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Figure5_RPC_Problem_1}\caption{Wider than figure text. Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.}
\end{figure}
```

but the image is still placed slightly to the right.

Comment: The correct form is `\begin{figure}\centering\includegraphics...\end{figure}`. You can use `\fbox{\includegraphics...}` in order to see the real dimensions of your image. Maybe you are having some white space on one side.

Comment: As LaRiFaRi suggest, I would think there is some whitespace in the image itself. Open `Figure5_RPC_Problem_1` in an image viewer and check, crop if needed. Sidenote: As `figure` is a floating environment (i.e. it can move), it doesn't make sense to have it inside a `center` environment. Most likely it will simply float away and leave you with unwanted vertical space in the text.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I have rewritten the code but the image is still on the right I am cropping it now.

Comment: Try if the same happen iy you instead your real images use `example-image` from `includegraphix` package: `\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Figure5_RPC_Problem_1}\caption{Wider than figure text. Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.}` If it is centered (there is no reason to not be) than read above comments again!

Comment: Cropping the image to the left did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After cropping the image, I've used the following latex code:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{Figure5_RPC_Problem_1}\caption{Wider than figure text. Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.Wider than figure text.}
\end{figure}
```

In lyx, the `graphicx` package must be included in the preamble:

Go to Document <kbd>→</kbd>  Settings <kbd>→</kbd> Preamble and add

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```